# join issue, what are the best alternatives?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, join, informix

Q:

I have 5 or 6 tables , and i need data from these tables :
i make the following join statement to accomplish my query.

```
SELECT d.batch_no,d.studytype_code,d.camp_code,d.dep_code,d.start_date,d.end_date,a.year,a.term_code,c.studytype_name ,e.dep_name_ar,f.camp_name_ar
FROM llkbatch a , llkbatch_category b , mm19studytype c ,llkbatch_exception d  ,llkdepartment e,llkcamp f
WHERE   a.batch_no = b.batch_no
AND  b.studytype_code = c.studytype_code 
AND  b.batch_no = d.batch_no
AND b.studytype_code = d.studytype_code 
AND d.dep_code = e.dep_code
AND d.camp_code = f.camp_code
```

but i think that the `join` sometimes is less performance way to do things like that,is there any alternative to this in a `programming way` or in the `database layer`, i mean alternatives to joins in general and when should i go away from the joins.
thanks a lot.

Comment: What makes you think that `join` s are bad for perfomance?

Comment: Are you actually facing any performance issue? Or is this like "Could become slower"?

Comment: no but my team leader told me that the joins are evil , and less performance way , and told me that i should find alternatives every time i face case like that.i use informix dbms.

Comment: Your team leader is an idiot, er, I mean, misinformed!

Comment: I believe his team lead doesn't believe in `normalisation` !

Comment: having several joins can be expensive, depending on the sizes of each table being joined and whether or not indexes have been created to support the joined columns. denormalizing tables usually translates to improved speed, at the expense of data redundancy and increased table size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more modern ANSI join syntax that will make your joins more readable, but it should not affect performance:

```
SELECT d.batch_no,d.studytype_code,d.camp_code,d.dep_code,d.start_date,d.end_date,
       a.year,a.term_code,c.studytype_name ,e.dep_name_ar,f.camp_name_ar
FROM ra1batch a 
JOIN ra1batch_category b ON a.batch_no = b.batch_no
JOIN ra1studytype c ON b.studytype_code = c.studytype_code
JOIN ra1batch_exception d ON b.batch_no = d.batch_no
                         AND b.studytype_code = d.studytype_code 
JOIN rr1department e ON d.dep_code = e.dep_code
JOIN rr2camp f ON d.camp_code = f.camp_code
```

Comment: if i use stored procedure instead, this will increase the performance or not.

Comment: No it won't.  The stored procedure still has to get and join the data, either by running the very same query or (worse) by running several queries and programmatically combining the results.  I suggest you get your team leader a book like "SQL for Dummies"!

Comment: you should try making it into stored procedure and then check out the performance.. at least you would have a benchmark on which you need to improve

Comment: :):)he told me that he sure that the .net (asp.net) has the ability to get the data programatically without the joins among many tables!.

Comment: Right, so he wants you tun run 6 queries (1 per table) and then with some looping and whatnot in your code combine (or "join") the data into rows.  What a plank!

Comment: Sure you could do it programmaticaly in asp.net (or any other language for that matter) but it wouldn't be any faster and likely much slower. RDBMS' are designed to handle precisely this kind of thing. Best let them get on with it. If you're seeing slow performance then start by looking at query plans and indexes.

Comment: one more question please, when should i go away from joins?

Comment: Never - if you want to combine data from 2 or more tables, joins are **the** way to do it!

Comment: "if you want to combine data from 2 or more tables" ...erm, what about `UNION`? :)

Comment: If you were to use LINQ in ASP.Net and you wrote some C# code (i.e. not SQL code) to get data from two related tables, guess what would happen? Your C# code would _automatically translate that into a SQL statement with a join_ because that's the most efficient way to do it. Either you misunderstood your team leader or he is a twit (also an idiot and a plank). Again consider that databases have many intelligent and optimised ways to do joins (using the best algorithm, using indexes, using caching etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The query you have written in your question follows the syntax of Oracle. But you use joins as if you are using SQL Server. It will give you better performance in comparison with your current query.

The below query will parse faster compared to your current query.

```
SELECT d.batch_no, d.studytype_code, d.camp_code, …
FROM ra1batch a
INNER JOIN ra1batch_category b on a.batch_no = b.batch_no
```

Comment: It isn't "Oracle syntax", it is just pre-ANSI JOIN syntax.  Oracle has supported ANSI joins for about 15 years.

Comment: I am not much familiar with Oracle. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @Tony Andrews: "Oracle has supported ANSI joins for about 15 years" -- you are a little off: IIRC the SQL-92 `OUTER JOIN` syntax wasn't supported in Oracle until v9 circa 2001.